# Monkey patch to add a missing interface

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

How can be [collective.monkeypatcher](https://pypi.org/project/collective.monkeypatcher/) used to add a `IFooBar` in a `someproduct`?

This is what I tried and it's wrong (because `IFooBar` doesn't exist in original product.)

```
<monkey:patch description="Create missing FooBar interface"
              class="someproduct.interfaces.IFooBar"
              original="IFooBar"
              replacement="myproduct.patches.IFooBar"
              docstringWarning="true" />
```

The error is `ConfigurationError: ('Invalid value for', 'class', 'ImportError: Module someproduct.interfaces has no global IFooBar')`.

My final goal is to skip this error: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'someproduct.interfaces.IFooBar'>: attribute lookup someproduct.interfaces.IFooBar failed` received when I try to activate / deactivate add-ons.

It is because I have installed a new version of `someproduct` that has `IFooBar`, then I reverted to an older version (that has not `IFooBar`) without uninstalling the add-on.

**Update:**

Replacing the line:

```
class="someproduct.interfaces.IFooBar"
```

with

```
class="someproduct.interfaces"
```

it's the same thing. Error:
`ConfigurationError: Original IFooBar in <module 'someproduct.interfaces' from '/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/someproduct-1.2-py2.7.egg/some/path/interfaces.pyc'> not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Just add: `ignoreOriginal="true"`